# NOT operator is going to make 2 mutually exclusive groups

Tags: apache-pig

In my script I read from multiple files and I use one regex and its complement to partition the records in 2 groups/classes. I expected two mutually exclusive classes but I did not find when I counted the records... 
So I have added one SPLIT section to find the 'rest' of the records that are not covered by my constraint and its complement. The result (again) was not the expected one... 
What is wrong in my script? Thanks for your help!

The expected 'math':

```
 input: 1464 records
 ouputs: 264 + 870 + ???_330__??
```

the script:

```
A = load 'input/*' using PigStorage('\t','-tagPath') as (src:chararray, content:chararray);
Ac = foreach (GROUP A all) generate COUNT(A);

B = filter A by content MATCHES '(^\\b[BCDFMSTX].*\\b\\:\\s{1}.*)';
Bc = foreach (GROUP B all) generate COUNT(B);

Bnot = filter A by NOT content MATCHES '(^\\b[BCDFMSTX].*\\b\\:\\s{1}.*)';
Bcnot = foreach (GROUP Bnot all) generate COUNT(Bnot);

SPLIT A INTO SET1 IF (content MATCHES '(^\\b[BCDFMSTX].*\\b\\:\\s{1}.*)')
              , SET2 IF (NOT content MATCHES '(^\\b[BCDFMSTX].*\\b\\:\\s{1}.*)')
              , SETn OTHERWISE;

STORE SET1 into 'output/set1';
STORE SET2 into 'output/set2';
STORE SETn into 'output/setn';
```

the result:

```
 Input(s):
 Successfully read 1464 records (49024 bytes) from: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dag/input/*"

 Output(s):
 Successfully stored 264 records (25276 bytes) in: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dag/output/set1"
 Successfully stored 870 records (84190 bytes) in: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dag/output/set2"
 Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/dag/output/setn"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that in 330 cases content is `null`. If you replace the boolean expression by `content is null OR NOT content MATCHES '(^\\b[BCDFMSTX].*\\b\\:\\s{1}.*)'` it should work.

That being said, I don't think that this is very intuitive and I think Pig should either throw a NullPointerException or at least log a warning.

Comment: hi , yes it's correct. When i filtered records by content is null, the result is 330.